# How to sort ng-repeat key value pair getting from firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularjs-ng-repeat

i new to angularJS i am getting key value pair from firebase how to sort by timeStamp to show latest at top.
please help me . thanks in advance, orderBy and reverse not working

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://firebaseio.com/notifications/");
var fb = $firebase(ref);

var syncArreglo = fb.$asObject();

syncArreglo.$loaded().then(function() {
    angular.forEach(syncArreglo, function (value, key) {
        if(syncArreglo.value != null){
            syncArreglo.value.firebaseKey = syncArreglo.key;
        }
    });
});

syncArreglo.$bindTo($scope,'chats');

<ul class="menu" ng-repeat="(key , value) in chats">
```

Comment: provide code that how you did so far about getting key value pair

Comment: please check the code

Answer (score 0):

Let say you have charts json as:

```
$scope.chats = [
        {item: 'a',  created : '2016-12-01', num :1},
        {item: 'b',  created : '2015-12-01' , num :4},
        {item: 'c',  created : '2018-12-01', num :5},
    ];
```

To sort item , you need to provide filter  `orderBy : sortItem : true` as in

```
<ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in chats | orderBy : sortItem : true">
            <li>{{value}} :: {{value.created}}</li>
        </ul>
```

Your controller will have function **sortitem** which will tell the sorting item function

**Conrtoller**

```
 $scope.sortItem = function(d) {
      var dateing = new Date(d.created); 
      return dateing;  
  };
```

Play around jsfiddle  : http://jsfiddle.net/agjqN/688/

Comment: thanks but its not working, am using angularJS 1.4.0

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/LcYSMu?p=preview  Used 1.4.0 angularjs version , here its working